# Ошибка установки BeutifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Не получается установить библиотеку BeautifulSoup как через cmd так и через PyCharm. В cmd выдает ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать? что это такое и что это может быть?
Благодарю за ответы.

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытались установить BeautifulSoup3, данная версия **не** работает с Python 3.x.

> Beautiful Soup 3 works only under Python 2.x.

Решений 2:

1. Установить BeautifulSoup4, он работает с версиями питона 2.7+ и 3.x - как раз ваш вариант

> Beautiful Soup 4 works on both Python 2 (2.7+) and Python 3.

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
либо найти beautifulsoup4 в PyCharm
```

2. Работать на Python 2.x, что не совсем рационально, но как вариант решил упомянуть

Comment: pip install bs4

Comment: [The current release is Beautiful Soup 4.6.0 (May 7, 2017). You can install Beautiful Soup 4 with pip install beautifulsoup4.](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker я так понимаю beautifulsoup4 не подходит мне по описанию. мне нужно парсер написать для xml файла

Comment: @NikitaAfanasev не совсем понимаю, почему другая версия одной и той же библиотеки вам не подходит :)

[Вот тут есть простой и небольшой пример парсинга примитивного xml документа](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~takebaya/cent110/xml_parse/xml_parse.html)